# How do I remove trees from the moat around my fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The moat around my fortress has trees that may be used by monsters to climb inside. Can I get rid of them without removing the water from the moat?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found a way: use a ballista!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is an incredibly dwarven solution.

Comment: here I was going to suggest building a floor to get to it, the cut it down and dig out the channel. but this works too!

Comment: My first thought was magma, but this is much more creative!